# Proving $\;\ln k \geq \int_{k-\frac{1}{2}}^{k+ \frac{1}{2}}\ln x dx$

Tags: integration, geometry, inequality, logarithms

I'm trying to prove  $$\ln k \geq \int_{k-\frac{1}{2}}^{k+ \frac{1}{2}}\ln x dx$$

In other words, I'm trying to show why the area of the rectangle with height $\ln k$ and width $1$ bounds the area under the graph of $f(x)=\ln x$ in the interval $[k-\frac{1}{2},k+\frac{1}{2}].$

I tried to integrate but got stuck. Any ideas for an elegant proof for this?

Answer (score 4):

Logarithm is a concave function, by [Jensen inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality),

$$\ln E\left( U\right) \ge E\left( \ln (U)\right)$$

where $U \sim Uni\left( k-\frac12, k+\frac12\right)$.

$$\ln k \ge \int_{k-\frac12}^{k+\frac12} \ln (x)\, dx$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are there any other ways of proving it? unfortunately I'm not familiar with this inequality. Also, why is $E(\ln (U))$ equals the integral in the RHS?

Comment: For $Uni(k-\frac12, k+\frac12)$, the density is $1$ on the support. Hence to compute $E(\ln U) = \int_{k-\frac12}^{k+\frac12} ( \ln x )f(x)\, dx = \int_{k-\frac12}^{k+\frac12}  \ln x \cdot 1 \, dx $

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Note that $\ln$ is concave. You can generally show that for concave functions $f$, we have $$f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) \ge \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\, dx.$$ (This is a continuous form of **Jensen's inequality**.)

Comment: Could you please explain how can I show this inequality? Is there a way to prove it without using probability?

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for a comment but written for your curiosity.*

You received good answers so I should use integration for illustration. Since, using one integration by parts,
$$\int \log(x)=(x-1)\log(x)$$ using the given bounds, the rhs is
$$\text{rhs}=\left(\frac{1}{2} (2 k+1) \left(\log \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)-1\right)\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2} (2 k-1) \left(\log \left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)-1\right)\right)$$ Considering at least that $k$ can be large, using Taylor expansions,
$$\text{rhs}=\log(k)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {c_n}{k^{2n}}$$ and all coefficients $c_n$ are negative. Their reciprocals are
$$\{24,320,2688,18432,112640,638976,3440640,17825792,89653248,440401920\}$$ and they are related to the coefficients of Chebyshev polynomials
$$c_n=\frac {2^{-(2 n+1)} } { n (2 n+1) }$$